# What is the difference between Vue routing and Inertia? does inertia reload partial page?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, inertiajs

What is the difference between vue-routing and laravel inertia? with vue routing component added in dom without page reloading. and with inertia component name is returned from server side does it reload partial page?

Answer (score 4):

Vue routing is defined in client-side, while Inertia routing is defined in server-side. If you are using Inertia, you don't need Vue Router. Simply create routes using your server-side framework of choice. Read their docs to spot more differences between them.

Inertia routing: https://inertiajs.com/routing

Vue routing: https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/routing.html

And yes, Inertia does partial reloads - https://inertiajs.com/partial-reloads

Comment: @Neha consider to accept the answer if it solved your question (: